# Mostrar (Exibir) o indice (Key) de uma array, porém não dever ser uma key fixa, tem que variar conforme $maior = max($classe);

Tags: php

```
    $classe = array(
        'Aluno 1: ' => 3.3,
        'Aluno 2: ' => 5,
        'Aluno 3: ' => 8,
        'Aluno 4: ' => 9.3,
        "Aluno 5: " => 4.5,
        "Aluno 6: " => 9.9,
        "Aluno 7: " => 8.8,
        "Aluno 8: " => 9,
        "Aluno 9: " => 6.8,
        "Aluno 10: " => 5.5
    );
    
 $media = 0;

 $div = 0;

    foreach($classe as $key => $notas){
        echo $key . $notas . "<br>";
    }

    foreach($classe as $key => $notas_alunos){
        $div += $notas_alunos;
        $media = $div / 10;
     
    }

    echo "<br> A MÉDIA DA SALA É: " . $media . "<br>";
    
    $maior = max($classe);
    echo "<br>" . $maior;
```

/* Deveria ser exibido "O aluno 6 tem a maior nota: 9.9" */

Comment: pq não aproveita o `foreach` que calcula a média e compara as notas para saber a maior?

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opa Murilo, Se entendi corretamente, você quer usar o array $classe para calcular a média da sala e depois mostrar o aluno (chave do array) com a maior nota, correto?

Desse modo o seguinte script deve te ajudar:

```
// Removi o dois pontos e espaço (: ) das chaves pra tornar intuitivo a saída das strings
$classe = array(
    'Aluno 1' => 3.3,
    'Aluno 2' => 5,
    'Aluno 3' => 8,
    'Aluno 4' => 9.3,
    "Aluno 5" => 4.5,
    "Aluno 6" => 9.9,
    "Aluno 7" => 8.8,
    "Aluno 8" => 9,
    "Aluno 9" => 6.8,
    "Aluno 10" => 5.5
);

foreach($classe as $aluno => $nota){
    // Ao usar aspas duplas você pode interpolar as variaveis na string pra tornar mais legivel
    echo "$aluno: $nota <br>";
}

// Media calculada dividindo a soma de todas as notas pelo numero de notas
$media = array_sum($classe) / count($classe) ;

// Retornando o maior valor no array utilizando a função max
$maiorNota = max($classe);

// A função array_search pode ser usada para retornar a chave de um valor 
$alunoComMaiorNota = array_search($maiorNota, $classe);



echo "<br> A MÉDIA DA SALA É: $media <br>";

echo "$alunoComMaiorNota tem a maior nota: $maiorNota";
```

A saída será:

```
Aluno 1: 3.3
Aluno 2: 5
Aluno 3: 8
Aluno 4: 9.3
Aluno 5: 4.5
Aluno 6: 9.9
Aluno 7: 8.8
Aluno 8: 9
Aluno 9: 6.8
Aluno 10: 5.5

A MÉDIA DA SALA É: 7.01
Aluno 6 tem a maior nota: 9.9
```

Espero ter ajudado e sinta-se a vontade pra perguntar qualquer coisa =]